# Change the action in AuthorizeAttribute filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionresult, authorize-attribute

If a user is not authorized to execute an action, in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`, I redirect the user to the error action. This results in a 302 error.

For example from `/Home/Index`, the user would be taken to `/Error/Unauthorized`.

Instead of the redirect, how do I change the `ActionResult` in the `filterContext.Response` so that the user sees the unauthorized page without a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

```
filterContext.Response = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/Error/Unauthorized.cshtml"
};
```